# Loading JSON file error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, spacy, named-entity-recognition, information-extraction

I am trying to train SpaCy NER model to identify my dataset locations.
The json training data sample looks like this:

```
[ ("Try searching in  Gloucestershire or Somerset", {"entities" : [ (37, 45,"GPE") ] } ) ]
```

then I try to load the JSON file to my colab notebook:

```
json_file_path = "/content/sample_data/trainData.json"
with open(json_file_path, 'r') as j:
 TRAIN_DATA = json.loads(j.read())
```

to give me this error:

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am still a newbie and I'm still figuring out how to train the model so, I would highly appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you share `print(j.read())` ? Because parenthesis aren't part of JSON spec, your first code is python code

Comment: Thank you, I changed the parenthesis and saved it in a variable.